# create md5 hash from a recursive file listing when some paths have spaces

Tags: find, filenames, xargs, recursive

I need to create an md5 hash of every directory and file inside of one main directory. The only thing that is keeping me from success is figuring out a way around files with a space in the path.

I am using find for the recursive listing (I have read that find is the best way of doing this):

```
c5-26-1# find /root/newdir
/root/newdir
/root/newdir/1
/root/newdir/2
/root/newdir/3
/root/newdir/4
/root/newdir/5
/root/newdir/newdir2
/root/newdir/newdir2/1
/root/newdir/newdir2/2
/root/newdir/new
/root/newdir/dir
/root/newdir/new dir
```

When I try this with md5 I get two different outcomes, neither of which work:

```
c5-26-1# md5 $(find /root/newdir) # same outcome using for loop
MD5 (/root/newdir) = bc79a580f6c932937f6fcd454747db72
MD5 (/root/newdir/1) = 94ca98295946310ce88e185ea57486d5
MD5 (/root/newdir/2) = 8432051f64459be5a5e73dc2abd91795
MD5 (/root/newdir/3) = d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
MD5 (/root/newdir/4) = d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
MD5 (/root/newdir/5) = d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
MD5 (/root/newdir/newdir2) = 722165901468b9596dbdddfe118759fb
MD5 (/root/newdir/newdir2/1) = d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
MD5 (/root/newdir/newdir2/2) = d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
MD5 (/root/newdir/new) = 89d042c5f9d6ba485a654b543685ea86
MD5 (/root/newdir/dir) = 148538718feba14839f5d1072854c5f4
MD5 (/root/newdir/new) = 89d042c5f9d6ba485a654b543685ea86
MD5 (dir) = 148538718feba14839f5d1072854c5f4
```

or

```
c5-26-1# find -X /root/newdir | xargs md5
find: /root/newdir/new dir: illegal path
MD5 (/root/newdir) = bc79a580f6c932937f6fcd454747db72
MD5 (/root/newdir/1) = 94ca98295946310ce88e185ea57486d5
MD5 (/root/newdir/2) = 8432051f64459be5a5e73dc2abd91795
MD5 (/root/newdir/3) = d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
MD5 (/root/newdir/4) = d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
MD5 (/root/newdir/5) = d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
MD5 (/root/newdir/newdir2) = 722165901468b9596dbdddfe118759fb
MD5 (/root/newdir/newdir2/1) = d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
MD5 (/root/newdir/newdir2/2) = d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
MD5 (/root/newdir/new) = 89d042c5f9d6ba485a654b543685ea86
MD5 (/root/newdir/dir) = 148538718feba14839f5d1072854c5f4
```

How do I account for directories with spaces?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`xargs` is rarely useful, because it expects input quoted in a highly peculiar way that no common tool produces. And as you've noticed `mycommand $(find …)` is no good, because it first concatenates all the file names and then splits at whitespace.

Use the `-exec` primary of `find` to make it execute `md5` with no intervening shell that would require quoting. If your implementation of `find` is reasonably current, then you can make it do what `xargs` is famous for, which is to invoke the `md5` program once per batch of arguments.

```
find /root/newdir -type f -exec md5 {} +
```

If your `find` doesn't support `-exec … {} +`, replace the `+` by `\;`. This makes `find` invoke `md5` for each file in turn. It's slightly slower, but available everywhere.

Answer (score 8):

Why not just use the [md5deep](http://md5deep.sourceforge.net/) tool that does exactly this? Most Linux distributions include it, usually in a package called `md5deep`.

Comment: I am working on with a FreeBSD variant, I don't have the option to install anything that isn't already on it and md5deep is not installed.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `-exec` switch to `find` I think that will automatically escape it for you.